# Haskell getting to the tuple

Tags: haskell, error-handling

I have a function in Haskell defined as (Error is a data type)

```
data Error a = Woops | Nice a deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

mixIt :: Int -> Int -> (Error (Int, Int))
```

How can I get to the return tuple, I have tried;

```
fst (mixIt 2 2)
```

But it gives an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fst` is a function with the type `(a, b) -> a` (well, we're using it in a more specific way, as `(Int, Int) -> Int`) but we're applying it to `mixIt 2 2` which has the type `Error (Int, Int)`. This is the source of our error.

In order to fix it we need to inspect the `Error` value we get back from `mixIt` by pattern matching on it

```
 case mixIt 2 2 of
   Nice tuple -> fst tuple
```

We can explicitly pattern match on the case where we have a `Nice` constructor which has the tuple we want as an argument. However there's a problem because `mixIt` might also return `Woops`, the other constructor of `Error`. We need to handle that case separately otherwise our program will fail at runtime (a very bad thing)

```
 case mixIt 2 2 of
   Nice tuple -> fst tuple
   Whoops -> ... some Haskell code to produce another tuple ...
```

once you fill in that last branch of the case expression you're set to go.

Comment: Thank you for this, I really couldn't find anything about this on the web, as I wasn't sure of what to search for a solution. Thanks again, was a big help!